# Google forms list items with dynamic goto section

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I found this answer posted here earlier.

```
function GoToPage() {
    var form = FormApp.openById('MY FORM');
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MY SPREADSHEET");
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("MY SHEET");
    var list = form.getItemById("MY MULTIPLE CHOICE ID").asListItem()  
    var pagebreak01 = form.getItemById("PAGE BREAK ID 1").asPageBreakItem();
    var pagebreak02 = form.getItemById("PAGE BREAK ID 2").asPageBreakItem();
    var pagebreak03 = form.getItemById("PAGE BREAK ID 3").asPageBreakItem();
    var choice1 = sheet.getRange("RANGE 1 FROM MY SHEET").getValues();
    var choice2 = sheet.getRange("RANGE 2 FROM MY SHEET").getValues();
    var choice3 = sheet.getRange("RANGE 3 FROM MY SHEET").getValues();  
    list.setChoices([
      list.createChoice(choice1, pagebreak01),
      list.createChoice(choice2, pagebreak02),
      list.createChoice(choice3, pagebreak03)]); 
    }
```

when using a range larger than 1 in the choice# variables, this makes just one choice with all the items in the range separated by commas. how can I use this to make a list of choices that has a dynamic range?

My exact choices should be:
"** Add Location **" , goto newLocation section of form.
location 1, goto next section.
location 2, goto next section.
location 3, ect....

If you select new location and fill out the form to add a new location the script then adds that location name to the choices for the next time you fill out the form. so this list is continually growing larger.

```
function updateForm() {

  var locationForm = form.getItemById("413015265").asListItem();
  var equipmentForm = form.getItemById("2123556695").asListItem();
  var newLocation = form.getItemById('231469190').asPageBreakItem();
  var newItem = form.getItemById('90044295').asPageBreakItem();
  var gotoIssue = form.getItemById('1493817332').asPageBreakItem();
  var gotoLocation = form.getItemById('1425783734').asPageBreakItem();
  var locations = tblLocations.getRange(2,2,tblLocations.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var items = tblItems.getRange(2,2,tblItems.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  items = items.sort();
  locations = locations.sort();
  locationForm.setChoices([
    locationForm.createChoice("** Add Location **",newLocation),
    locationForm.createChoice(locations,gotoIssue)
  ]);
  equipmentForm.setChoices([
    equipmentForm.createChoice("** Add Item **",newItem),
    equipmentForm.createChoice(items,gotoLocation)
  ]);

}
```

after running the above script I ended up with only 2 choices. 1 new location/item entry which works correctly, and 1 entry with all the current locations/items in the spreadsheet already, separated by commas. Can i just run a foreach loop inside the setChoices command?

Comment: list.setChoices() takes one parameter which is an array of choices and it does put any limit upon the length of the array which makes it possible to be dynamic. [setChoices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item#setChoices(Choice)) the values is in any range can be return as and array of any length.

Comment: Thanks for the replay Cooper I do not quite understand what you are saying though. Do you mean it doesn't put any limit upon the length?  Can you please post an example of what you mean?

Comment: I'm simply saying that set Choices can be an array of any length so taking values from an array of any size is ok and there fore it can be dynamic.  You can try if for yourself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function updateForm() {
  var locationForm = form.getItemById("413015265").asListItem();
  var equipmentForm = form.getItemById("2123556695").asListItem();
  var newLocation = form.getItemById('231469190').asPageBreakItem();
  var newItem = form.getItemById('90044295').asPageBreakItem();
  var gotoIssue = form.getItemById('1493817332').asPageBreakItem();
  var gotoLocation = form.getItemById('1425783734').asPageBreakItem();
  var locations = tblLocations.getRange(2,2,tblLocations.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var items = tblItems.getRange(2,2,tblItems.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var locationChoices = [];
  var itemChoices = [];
  locationChoices[0] = locationForm.createChoice("** Add Location **",newLocation);
  itemChoices[0] = equipmentForm.createChoice("** Add Item **",newItem);
  items = items.sort();
  locations = locations.sort();
  for (var i=0;i<tblLocations.getLastRow()-1;i++){
    locationChoices[i+1]= locationForm.createChoice(locations[i],gotoIssue);
  }
  locationForm.setChoices(locationChoices);
  for (var i=0;i<tblItems.getLastRow()-1;i++){
    itemChoices[i+1]= equipmentForm.createChoice(items[i],gotoLocation);
  }
  equipmentForm.setChoices(itemChoices);

}
```

I was able to figure it out. It's probably not the most beautiful solution but it works. :)